# Как сделать перенаправление на страницу в условии?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, циклы, редирект, обработка-ошибок

У меня есть цикл с добавлением данных в базу данных. Я бы хотел в этом цикле сделать перенаправление на страницу входа. Но header не работает в теле сайта. И как решить эту ситуацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Узнать [*где* работает РНР](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke) и поместить обработчик формы ДО начала вывода HTML

Comment: Или, для начала, лучше даже в отдельный файл

Comment: все заголовки должны устанавливаться *ДО* вывода любого контента. Никаких `echo`, никакого `html`.